# Loop values from array into JS grid

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have been wracking my brain on this one, nothing seems to work and I'm not sure what is being overlooked.

I have an array that I am pulling from a (crap)API using $output below, it looks like:

```
Array
(
[title] => Servers
[servs] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [server_name] => localhost
                [total_ram] => 15922
                [ram] => 12844
                [total_space] => 931
                [space] => 263
                [version] => 2.7.9
                [numvps] => 4
                [alloc_ram] => 5120
                [alloc_space] => 45
                [virts] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => kvm
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [server_name] => VS999
                [total_ram] => 15922
                [ram] => 5897
                [total_space] => 1397
                [space] => 974
                [version] => 2.7.9
                [numvps] => 4
                [alloc_ram] => 10240
                [alloc_space] => 200
                [virts] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => kvm
                    )

            )
```

Using this print_r in PHP it displays all the data just fine.

```
$output = $admin->servers();
print_r($output);
```

I'm trying to pull out specific values from that array and loop them into a grid (using vue.js) which looks like this:

```
{ Node: 'vs999', Disk_Free: 974, Total_Disk: 1397, Disk_Free_Percent: 69, Free_RAM: 5897, Total_RAM: 15922, Free_RAM_Percent: 37, VMs: 4, Version: '2.7.9' },
```

Is there any easy way to accomplish this? I've tried printing single values from the array itself such as "server_name" but I can't get that even working - just a blank page no matter what I try.

Comment: Turn on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Check the javscript console for information. `echo json_encode($data)` to send data to JS.

Comment: "I've tried printing single values from the array" and how did you try to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Call API to get servers
$rawData = $admin->servers();

// Data mapping
$map = [
'server_name' => 'Node',
'space' => 'Disk_Free',
'total_space' => 'Total_Disk',
];

// Remap data
$data = [];
foreach ($rawData['servs'] as $row) {
$item = [];
foreach ($map as $from => $to) {
    $item[$to] = $row[$from];
}
$data[] = $item;
}

// encode JSON
$json = json_encode($data);

// Done and done
echo $json;
```

This seems to be doing pretty close to what I need, thank you for the error reporting and json_encode function!